# Java ScheduledThreadPool to use extra threads if a task duration exceeds period

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, threadpoolexecutor

So, lets say I have a `ScheduledExecutorService` with 10 threads, generated as such, and I start a periodic task to run once a minute.

```
svc = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(10);
svc.scheduleAtFixedRate(myRunnable, 0, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

This is a perfect way to make `myRunnable` run once a minute. Now let's say the execution of `myRunnable` takes *longer* than a minute (therefore the task duration now exceeds the task period). The current behavior that I have noticed is that the thread pool will wait until `myRunnable` completes execution before running again. It looks like what I am saying with my code is to schedule the task but only occupy one thread in the pool with `myRunnable`.

Is there an option/another API/additional method call where I can make this thread pool to just grab the next available thread and run if the first thread hasn't completed execution in one minute? (Or am I doing this wrong?)

Comment: This is intended behavior: From the JavaDoc for scheduleAtFixedRate: "If any execution of this task takes longer than its period, then subsequent executions may start late, but will not concurrently execute."

Comment: I can't believe I missed that, thank you. I read the JavaDoc for `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool` and didn't see anything, but I did forget to check the actual `scheduleAtFixedRate` JavaDoc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not schedule your Runnable for one-time-only execution (after a delay), then at the beginning of your Runnable schedule it again?

Comment: That will definitely accomplish what I am trying to do if I place it at the beginning of my `Runnable`, granted that I can guarantee that my `Runnable` will at least always get called (which I cannot think of a situation where it wouldn't _at least_ get called, even if it is _followed_ by an exception). I was wondering if there was anything built into the API for this, but it appears not to be the case.

Comment: @MichaelPlautz  This suggestion will result in the task running with a slightly variable period that is slightly longer than one minute.  If that's acceptable, then go for it.  But, if you need the task to start on precise, one minute intervals, consider scheduling a periodic task that runs once a minute, and does nothing except schedule the _real_ task to run once, immediately.

Comment: Note that re-scheduling the task itself might result in multiple threads accessing the task concurrently if task execution overlaps as described in the question. So make sure it is either stateless or implemented in a thread-safe way! (That's maybe one reason why there is no such built-in feature)